# trying to print out text by by letting the user input the number of columns and rows, where am I going wrong?

Tags: python

```
print ("number of rows")
rows = int(input())
print ("number of columns")
col = int(input())
for noofrows in range(0,rows,1):
    print(":)")
    for noofcol in range(0,col,1):
        print(":)",end="")
:)
:):):):)
:):):):)
:):):)
this is the output i get
```

When I do 3 by 3 it gives me a list of 1 then 4 then 4 then 3 smile faces.

Comment: What? can you show us output better ?

Comment: You can [edit] your post to include sample output

Comment: Do you have a question? All I see here is code that produces exactly the output you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the `print`s are incorrect.

```
for noofrows in range(rows): #same as range(0,row,1)
    #don't print a smiley here
    #print(":)")
    for noofcol in range(col): #same as range(0,col,1)
        print(":)",end="")
    #print an empty string instead and at the end of the loop
    print("")
```

Equivalent code in Python 2 given `row` as 3 and `col` as 3 outputs

> :)  :)  :)
>   :)  :)  :)
>   :)  :)  :)